# JDBC: How to read MySQL point format

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, geometry, point

I have a 2D POINT column in MySQL. I use JDBC to read it into a Java Object. The result is a byte[25]. I am wondering what format this is so I can convert it to my point (e.g. double values)

The point is set like this:

```
UPDATE ... SET point=GeomFromText('POINT(18 63)')
```

resulting bytes in the DB:

```
0x00000000010100000000000000000032400000000000804F40
```

Comment: Can you share the table description regarding said `POINT` column and how are you currently trying to query the table? `GeomFromText('POINT(18 -63)')` is something you'd use when INSERTing data into the column.

Comment: Is the name of the column really `point`? That is a MySQL reserved word so you should escape it with back tics (`\`point\``) in the query, or preferrably rename the column.

Comment: It was just an example name, I named it "start". It works normaly with the ST_X/ST_Y functions. But I need to select it using * for all columns

Comment: It is a byte for the byte order mark, 8 bytes for a constant for POINT, and then twice 8 bytes for the coordinates. There seems to be a WKBReader that can convert, using `ResultSet.getBytes()`.

Comment: Thanks Joop, the WKBReader worked. The format was in little endian, so straight double conversion gave wrong result.

Comment: Please consider self-answering/accepting the solution that worked for you to make this question useful for others.

Answer (score 1):

It is usually a good practice to explicitly list all columns that you are querying from the table, but if you want to use the wildcard (`*`) and also the [`ST_X/Y()` point property functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-point-property-functions.html) for the coordinates, you could try with a table alias:

```
SELECT ST_X(t.myPointColumn) as x_coordinate, ST_Y(t.myPointColumn) as y_coordinate, t.* 
      FROM myTable t WHERE ...
```

In Java, you'd then access the coordinates with

```
myResultSet.getDouble("x_coordinate");
myResultSet.getDouble("y_coordinate");
```

Answer (score 1):

So for the solution I used code from the WKB reader: https://github.com/simplegeo/jts/tree/master/src/com/vividsolutions/jts/io

Since I didn't want to include it all, I just used the code for reading doubles in endian formats from ByteOrderValues.java:

```
/**
     * Read a long from a byte buffer in big endian format.
     * @param buf must be 8 bytes
     */
    public static long readLongFromBytesBigEndian(byte[] buf) {
            return    (long) (buf[0] & 0xff) << 56
                    | (long) (buf[1] & 0xff) << 48
                    | (long) (buf[2] & 0xff) << 40
                    | (long) (buf[3] & 0xff) << 32
                    | (long) (buf[4] & 0xff) << 24
                    | (long) (buf[5] & 0xff) << 16
                    | (long) (buf[6] & 0xff) <<  8
                    | (long) (buf[7] & 0xff);
    }

    /**
     * Read a long from a byte buffer in little endian format.
     * @param buf must be 8 bytes
     */
    public static long readLongFromBytesLittleEndian(byte[] buf) {
            return    (long) (buf[7] & 0xff) << 56
                    | (long) (buf[6] & 0xff) << 48
                    | (long) (buf[5] & 0xff) << 40
                    | (long) (buf[4] & 0xff) << 32
                    | (long) (buf[3] & 0xff) << 24
                    | (long) (buf[2] & 0xff) << 16
                    | (long) (buf[1] & 0xff) <<  8
                    | (long) (buf[0] & 0xff);
    }

    /**
     * Read a long from a byte buffer in big or little endian format.
     * @param bigEndian true for big endian, false for little endian
     * @param buf must be 8 bytes
     */
    public static double readDoubleFromBytes(byte[] buf, boolean bigEndian) {
        long longVal =  bigEndian ? readLongFromBytesBigEndian(buf)
                : readLongFromBytesLittleEndian(buf);
        return Double.longBitsToDouble(longVal);
    }

    /**
     * Read a long from a byte buffer in big or little endian format.
     * @param bigEndian true for big endian, false for little endian
     * @param buf must be 8 bytes length after offset
     */
    public static double readDoubleFromBytes(byte[] buf, int offset, boolean bigEndian) {
        byte[] bufOf8Bytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(buf, offset, offset + 8);
        return readDoubleFromBytes(bufOf8Bytes, bigEndian);
    }

    /**
     * Read a coordinate from a byte array in WKB format.
     * @param wkbBytes must be 25 bytes long
     */
    public static Coordinate readCoordinateFromWkbBytes(byte[] wkbBytes) {
        // Points are stored in MySQL marked as big endian, but in reality is little endian. Not good
        boolean isBigEndian = false; // readIsWkbBigEndianByteOrder(wkbBytes[0]);
        double x = readDoubleFromBytes(wkbBytes, 9, isBigEndian);
        double y = readDoubleFromBytes(wkbBytes, 17, isBigEndian);
        Coordinate coordinate = new Coordinate();
        coordinate.setX(x);
        coordinate.setY(y);
        return coordinate;
    }

    public static boolean readIsWkbBigEndianByteOrder(byte b) {
        final byte BIG_ENDIAN = 0;
        final byte LITTLE_ENDIAN = 1;
        return b == BIG_ENDIAN;
    }
```

Note: The first byte in my point, indicating big/little endian, was set to 0, which should be big endian according to WKBReader. However I found that littl endian was the actual format.